# In Functional Coverage, the feature file name duplicates on the serenity report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I see feature file name duplicates in serenity report as shown in the pic. Please advise as how to fix it. POM xml is below. I have searched for many  only forums but couldn't get appropriate one.

4.0.0
net.serenitybdd.starter
serenity-changehealthcare
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
jar

```
<name>EAPI Automation Developer Portal</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <serenity.version>2.2.0</serenity.version>
    <serenity.maven.version>2.2.0</serenity.maven.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>2.2.0</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <cucumber.version>5.5.0</cucumber.version>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <tags></tags>
    <parallel.tests>4</parallel.tests>
    <webdriver.base.url>chrome</webdriver.base.url>
    <browserstack.local.version>1.0.3</browserstack.local.version>
          <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
          <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray-plugins</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
      - To use Cucumber 4, exclude the old Cucumber 2 cucumber-core dependency from the serenity-core dependency
      - and include the Cucumber 4 cucumber-java and cucumber-junit dependencies.
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>browserstack-local-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber5</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
              <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
              <version>5.0.0</version>
          </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-single-page-report</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
              <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
              <version>5.0.0</version>
          </dependency>
</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <skip></skip>
            </configuration>
            


        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>**/CucumberTestSuite.java</includes>
                        <parallel>methods</parallel>
                        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <tags>${tags}</tags>
                <reports>single-page-html</reports>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
<profiles>


    <profile>
        <id>single</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/SingleTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>parallel</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/Parallel*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <parallel>classes</parallel>
                        <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                        <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

Can anyone please help on this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QnRg.png)

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Make sure your features are organised in a folder structure that reflects your requirements hierarchy, not just directly under `src/test/resources/features`, e.g.

```
src
  test
    resources
      features
         bookings
           book_a_flight.feature
           update_a_booking.feature
           view_bookings.feature
         account
           view_flight_history.feature
```

Also make sure there are no spaces in the file name or directory names.